# How can I convert a string to a command in Python?

Tags: python, command

I want to make a string into a command for my game but i don't now how to.
for example:
a = "print('Hello, world')"

Comment: You can use `eval`, but that is generally a terrible idea.

Comment: I don't think `eval` would work anyway, `exec` would run the command. print is a statement

Comment: A better question would be "what are you trying to achieve, and why did you think having the command in a string would be the best way to achieve it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick example:

```
def foo(var):
    print var

s = "foo('This is a test')"

exec s
```

the string s will be executed as any other python code